# Session replication in Tomcat - jdbc session persistence - custom or library implementation?

Tags: java, session, jdbc, session-replication

I'm implementing a multi-server Tomcat cluster web application (20+ servers). I want to do session replication by persisting the session to a common database via jdbc.

Is it worth my while to roll my own jdbc session persistence - or is there a strong and generic enough session replication implementation off the shelf in open source libraries?

The assumption here is that I'm looking for a "manager" that manages the persistence (to file or DB) of implementations of the following:

```
javax.servlet.http.Session
javax.servlet.http.SessionContext
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this: http://www.intelligrape.com/blog/2010/07/21/tomcat-6-session-persistence-through-jdbcstore/.

I'm trying to do the same thing as you, I found that this works. However, I experience a delay on the DB session insert. If you use that solution and found an answer to it let me know.